# How to add geometry to current section in arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, select

I looping through feature class. I want select the features that are 3 meters distance but not intersected features. I know we can do by select layer by location or attribute.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("ROAD_CENTERLINE",["shape@","S_CODE","CATEGORY","SUBCAT","oid@"]) as usc:
    for row in usc:
        geom,o=row[0],row[4]
        print o 
        sbl=arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("ROAD_CENTERLINE","INTERSECT",geom,"3 Meters","NEW_SELECTION","NOT_INVERT")
        sbl=arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("ROAD_CENTERLINE","INTERSECT",geom,"","REMOVE_FROM_SELECTION","NOT_INVERT")
        sbl=arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("ROAD_CENTERLINE","ARE_IDENTICAL_TO",geom,"","ADD_TO_SELECTION","NOT_INVERT")
```

to do above operation any simple step is there?

input

[image]

required output selection is
[image]

Comment: Why are you changing the contents of a selection set while in a cursor of that layer? I'm surprised this doesn't generate a micro-black hole and consume your motherboard in an X-ray burst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use da.SearchCursor with [distanceTo and disjoint methods of Polyline object](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/polyline.htm):

```
import arcpy, itertools

fc = r'C:\GIS\ArcMap_default_folder\Default.gdb\jl_sample' #Change
dist = 300 #Change

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features=fc, out_layer='lyr')

linelist = [row for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,['OID@','SHAPE@'])]

oids_to_select = []

for line1,line2 in itertools.combinations(linelist,2):
    if line1[1].disjoint(line2[1]) and line1[1].distanceTo(line2[1]) <= dist: #If the lines are disjoint and within dist, add OIDs to list
        oids_to_select.extend((line1[0],line2[0]))

if len(oids_to_select) > 0:
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view='lyr', where_clause="{0} IN{1}".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource='lyr', field=arcpy.Describe('lyr').OIDFieldName), tuple(oids_to_select)))
```

(All my lines are individual features, (7)):

[image]